# StructureMap configuration using app.config

Tags: .net, app-config, structuremap

I need to move my StructureMap configuration from a configuration class to my application's app.config.

Anyone know if the following code has an XML configuration equivalent?

```
For(typeof(ILogger<>)).Use(typeof(Log4NetLogger<>));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The StructureMap documentation says you can use the **DefaultInstance** Element

eg:

```
  <DefaultInstance 
    PluginType="StructureMap.Testing.Widget.IWidget,StructureMap.Testing.Widget" 
    PluggedType="StructureMap.Testing.Widget.ColorWidget,StructureMap.Testing.Widget" 
    Scope="Singleton" />
```

In the sample node above, the parts are:

1. PluginType -- Assembly qualified name of the PluginType (the "T" in ObjectFactory.GetInstance() )
2. PluggedType -- Assembly qualified name of the actual, concrete PluggedType
3. Scope -- Optionally defines the scope/lifecycle for this PluginType

http://structuremap.net/structuremap/XmlReference.htm#section7

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that with my templated interface and got a runtime error.  I've decided to keep the configuration in a Registry class and then reference the Registry class from the config file.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response.  I ended up deciding to keep with the code rather than using configuration.  Thanks for the help though!